# How to run Steam games using Wine?

Tags: wine, steam

I'd like to run AirMech Strike on Arch Linux using Wine (the latest currently available in Arch, 2.15). I have tried to download it in the Steam store but because I'm using Linux and it does not run natively on Linux (i.e. without Wine) it won't allow me to download it. Is there a way around this? After all WineHQ says that [some people managed to run the Steam version of the game in Wine successfully](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13548).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the Steam installer for Windows, install *that* using Wine, then run Steam itself using Wine. From there you’ll be able to run your Windows games (those that work with Wine), although you might not be able to buy any (for me, the library works, but not the store — that’s not much of an issue in general though since the store web site works fine).

For AirMech Strike in particular (and perhaps other free-to-play, early access games) you might need to launch the game directly, rather than through the library:

```
wine iexplore steam://run/206500
```